# How can you format all text headings

Tags: quill

What is the best way to color all headings? I have theming and want to automatically style headings a certain color for exiting text and new text.

Answer (score 0):

use the format method and specify the range index start and the length. If you want you can just insert html with the dangerous insert html in the doc with css value etc